# Reference C++ Runtime dll from .net dll

Tags: c++, .net, deployment

I have a .net dll that requires `msvcp110.dll` to run. When I use my .net dll in another app the app gives dependency errors. However, when I set the output path of my app to the same folder that contains `msvcp110.dll` it runs.

Is there some way I can reference `msvcp110.dll` in my .net dll such that consumers of my dll only have to add a reference to it for their app to run?

Thanks!

Comment: Installing the VS C++ runtime should clear that up - `msvcp110.dll` is part of the C++ runtime install. IIRC, the `110` is the VS2010 or VS2012 version...

Comment: It doesn't - the runtime dll has to be in the same folder as the consuming app. Or maybe I just need to restart my PC...

Comment: _However, when I set the output path of my app_ - do you run it from the IDE or from explorer?

Comment: I run it from the IDE

Comment: If the correct version of the runtime is installed and the problem is from the IDE, it may be a manifest problem of some sort. If it fails to run from explorer, an easier alternative then is to use a dependency viewer (such as Dependency Walker) to try diagnose the error.

Comment: It doesn't run from the explorer unless the app is in the same folder as it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness this seems to be the answer:

[Visual C++ 2010: Changes to MSVC runtime deployment (no more SxS with manifest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623780/visual-c-2010-changes-to-msvc-runtime-deployment-no-more-sxs-with-manifest)

I tried installing my dll to the GAC but to no avail - my app still complained about missing dependencies such as `msvcr100.dll`

o_O